# problem with printing multiple cck value inside node-type.tpl.php

Tags: entities

I am printing out this thing inside node-mytype.tpl.php (D6):

```
$dots = '';
$i = 0;
foreach($node->field_authors as $item) {
    $i = $i + 1;
    if ($i < count($node->field_authors)) { $dots = ',  '; } else { $dots = '.  '; };
    print '<span>'. $item['view'].$dots.'</span>';
}
```

Can somebody explain to me, why in this case printing `$item['view']` == succesfully printing cck field values? Shouldn't it be like `$item[i]['view']`?

When i'm printing cck multiple values im usually do it this way:

```
print $node->field_authors[0]['view'];
print $node->field_authors[1]['view']; // if 2 values
```

Explain to me please, i would really appreciate it...

Comment: See the PHP documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php -- The used form loops over the array given by `field_authors` array. On each loop, the value of the current element is assigned to $item and the internal array pointer is advanced by one (so on the next loop, you'll be looking at the next element).

To be able to use `$node->field_authors[$i]['view']`, you need to use the second form of foreach: foreach ($array as $key => $value) where $key will take the form 0,1,2..etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses foreach which takes `$node->field_authors[0,1,etc]` and relays that value through $item.  If you want to know the key for the current field inside your foreach loop, rewrite the code like this:

```
$dots = '';
$i = 0;
foreach($node->field_authors as $key => $item) {
    $i++;
    if ($i < count($node->field_authors)) { $dots = ',  '; } else { $dots = '.  '; };
    print '<span>'. $node->field_authors[$key]['view'].$dots.'</span>';
    // note: $node->field_authors[$key] is the same as $item['view']
}
```